# How can I change the names of paired/connected remote bluetooth devices?

Tags: settings, bluetooth

How can I change the name of my paired, remote Bluetooth devices (e.g., "Jabra a1.55.30" to "My headset")?

I'm comfortable using the CLI, if that is more efficient.

Comment: `ls -l /var/lib/bluetooth/`, then `sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC of onboard Bluetooth card]/names` though it does not seem to save the name once a connection is established to the external device (eg: "My newly renamed device name - 00" changes to headset's (EPROM?) string "H7"). Further advice appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

This information is still valid for Ubuntu 22.04

First of all, following steps are directly derived from answer by [@wolf](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/5565/wolf)

> **Note:** This answer has only been tested on Ubuntu 16.04(Dropped here from google search. Thought to add my experience)
>
> And I am **assuming** that:
>
> a) you have already paired (say) 'QY7' bluetooth earphones with your Ubuntu.
>
> b) it is listed as 'QY7' in the *System Settings -> (Hardware) Bluetooth -> Devices*

## Steps:

1. Get the *Mac address* of QY7 (We will refer to it as **MAC_ADDR_QY7**)

   System Settings ->

   (Hardware) Bluetooth ->

   In the 'Devices' list on left side, click on 'QY7' ->

   Note down the **'Address'** from the right side


   In my case, it is:

   Address   1C:52:db:7a:48:17

2) Get the *Mac address* of your computer's 'Bluetooth adapter' (**MAC_ADDR_BT_ADAP**)

You can open up a **terminal** and use following command: (source: [How to check bluetooth status via terminal][2])

```
user@user:~$ hcitool dev

Devices:
hci0    00:1A:5C:C4:B3:41
```

Thus, in my case, **00:1A:5C:C4:B3:41** is the *Mac address* of 'Bluetooth adapter'

3) Navigate to **/var/lib/bluetooth**

```
user@user:~$ cd /var/lib/bluetooth
```

4) We need to edit contents of a file called **info** corresponding to the paired 'QY7'.

But it is located in a folder structure **owned by 'root'**

For me, the easiest way to proceed was to use GEdit with root privileges and I am sharing the same:

```
user@user:~$ sudo gedit
(Enter your password)
```

5) In this opened 'Text Editor' -> 

Click 'Open' -> 

Other Documents... ->

Folder called **MAC_ADDR_BT_ADAP** (from step 2) ->

Folder called **MAC_ADDR_QY7** (from step 1) ->

Open file called **info**


 Sample contents of **info**:

```
[General]
Name=QY7
Class=0x240404
SupportedTechnologies=BR/EDR;
Trusted=true
Blocked=false
...
```

6) We **only** need to modify the value corresponding to **'Name'**. That is:

```
Name=modified_name_for_qy7
```

After modifying, save the file and close the text editor!

7) Now, we need to **restart the bluetooth service**.

```
user@user:~$ sudo service bluetooth restart
(Enter your password)
```

8) Verify that the name has been updated in *System Settings -> (Hardware) Bluetooth -> Devices*

Job complete!

Comment: These instructions worked for me on Linux Mint. Thanks!

Comment: After connecting to the device, it always reverts back to the original name.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use bluetooth so I can't test, but I [found](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/989817) something that should work:

1. When your device is connected, it [should be](https://askubuntu.com/q/554053/49899) listed in `/var/lib/bluetooth` by its MAC address. In that MAC address folder should be a `config` file. Edit the line that starts with `name` to the name you'd like.
2. Restart bluetooth: `sudo service bluetooth restart`

I believe this would be the same method to change your local bluetooth broadcast name, but you might need to [change another conf file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1308922/comments/6) too

Comment: After all wneh you open bluetooth settings dialog, you'll see device still has its default name and Name field at info file has been changed so to defive default name. I'd tried to rename couple of devices and result always the same. So there should be some service which changes info file on service restart or some other event.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as *Xristos*. I fixed creating a new line:

> `Alias=My_Device`

When the device connects, the Name variable is reset but not the Alias variable.
I hope this helps, I can't reply directly to *Xristos* because I don't have any points yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I've wanted to do this for months.

Comment: After [this PR](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth/pull/189), changing the Alias is the correct way to do this on elementary OS!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is once you connect the device, it reverts back to the original name so my headset is called "BH-M91". I changed it to "BT Headset" restarted the bluetooth service and it was fine. After I connected to "BT Headseet" it reverted back and stayed that way???

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib/bluetooth/[MAC ADDRESS of adapter]/[MAC ADDRESS of remote device]/info` file has **Name** for the device.

So you can change device name in this file as you wish.

Please, do not forget to restart of bluetooth demon after name change

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

However, it's not stable for me since some paring event make name return to original name. It's annoying and no idea under Bluez version 5.48 under Ubuntu 18.04